# Unable to use RJDBC at Shinyapp.io

Tags: r, shiny, db2, ibm-cloud, rjdbc

I have written a Shiny App which runs perfectly in my local machine. I have used RJDBC to connect to the DB2 database in IBM Cloud. The code is as follows.

```
#Load RJDBC
dyn.load('/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib')
# dyn.load('/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions/PriceIndex/libjvm.dylib')
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
```

As the path is hard coded, I copied the file libjvm.dylib to the Project directory and pointed to that. When I do this, R gives a fatal error.

I remove the absolute path and replaced with "./libjvm.dylib" and deployed the application on ShinyApp.io website. When I run the program, it gives a fatal error.

```
#Values for you database connection
dsn_driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
dsn_database = "BLUDB"            # e.g. "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname = "dashdb-entry-yp-lon02-01.services.eu-gb.bluemix.net"   # e.g. replace <yourhostname> with your hostname, e.g., "Db2 Warehouse01.datascientstworkbench.com"
dsn_port = "50000"                # e.g. "50000" 
dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"            # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid = "<UID>"              # e.g. userid
dsn_pwd = "<PWD>"            # e.g. password

#Connect to the Database
#jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "/Users/parthamajumdar/lift-cli/lib/db2jcc4.jar");
jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "db2jcc4.jar");
jdbc_path = paste("jdbc:db2://",  dsn_hostname, ":", dsn_port, "/", dsn_database, sep="");
conn = dbConnect(jcc, jdbc_path, user=dsn_uid, password=dsn_pwd)
```

Similarly, I copied the file "db2jcc4.jar" to my local project directory. If I point to the local project directory for this file in my local machine, the program works. However, when I deploy on ShinyApp.io, it gives fatal error.

Request your please letting me know what I need to do so that the application runs properly on the ShinyApp.io website.

The error is as follows when I run the application from Shiny server:

```
Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

Loading required package: nlme
This is mgcv 1.8-23. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  unable to load shared object '/srv/connect/apps/ExpenseAnalysis/Drivers/libjvm.dylib':
  /srv/connect/apps/ExpenseAnalysis/Drivers/libjvm.dylib: invalid ELF header
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: Edit your question to *show* the fatal-error details . Also, the Db2 jdbc driver needs two files to communicate with Unix/Linux/Windows versions of Db2. The other file is db2jcc_license_cu.jar.

Comment: Dear Sir, When I use this file from my app directory, the program aborts. Also, in the Shiny Server, the program aborts.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you Sir for your patience and help. I ran this command: sudo R CMD javareconf. Then I ran install.packages("rJava"). Then I commented out the line containing dyn.load(). Lastly, I moved db2jcc4.jar to a subdirectory. Now, the application runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is the following and it is independent of OS.

1. Create your own R package that contains the file you need somewhere in the `extdata` folder. As an example, your package could be `yourpackage` and the file would be something like `extdata/drivers/mydriver.lib`. Typically this would be stored at this location `inst/extdata/drivers`. See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html for details.
2. Store this package on github and if you want privacy you will need to work out how to grant an access token.
3. Use the `devtools` package to install it. The command would be something like this, `devtools::install_github("you/yourpackage", auth_token = "youraccesstoken")`. Do this once before deploying to Shiny.io. Ensure that you also do `library(yourpackage)`. The package submission process will work out that it needs to fetch from Github.
4. Use the following R code to find the file.
   `system.file('extdata/drivers/mydriver.lib, package='yourpackage')`. This will give you the full path to the file and you can use it.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. I made the following code: install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github("klutometis/roxygen")
library(roxygen2)

setwd("/Users/parthamajumdar/Documents/Solutions")
create("DriverLoader")

devtools::install_github("partha6369/DriverLoader", auth_token = "<token>")

library("DriverLoader")

system.file('extdata/drivers/libjvm.dylib', package='DriverLoader')
It returns an empty string.

Comment: I reckon you need to move the driver to `inst/extdata/drivers` on the physical machine where you build the R package.

Comment: Dear Sir, I moved it the inst directory. Now, it does not give any output. Please advice. > library("DriverLoader")
> system.file('extdata/drivers/libjvm.dylib', package='DriverLoader')
>

Comment: You need to create a folder called `inst/extdata/drivers` in the package definition and move the file to there. You will then need to rebuild the package.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using RStudio to create the R package by the way.

Comment: Dear Sir, I followed your steps. Now, when I create the package and upload to Git and then fetch the path, it works. However, when I use this in my Shiny App, it says that there is no such package. What need doing please? Thanks in advance. Regards, Partha

Comment: Dear Sir, I added this code: install.packages("./pkg/DriverLoaderPro_0.1.0.tar.gz",repos=NULL, type="source")
library("DriverLoaderPro")
JavaLib <- DriverLoaderPro::getLibDir()
print(JavaLib)

dyn.load(JavaLib)
Now, it is getting the directory properly, However, the program still aborts. What needs doing? Please advice. Regards, Partha

Comment: I think it is not getting from Git. Instead it is getting the file from local directory. That seems to be the problem. How can I get this file from Git?

Comment: Use `devtools::install_github` as described in step 3. I can see your repository on Github and it does not need a token since it is public. You do need to create the correct folder structure - i.e. `inst/extdata/drivers` and push that to Github.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you Sir for your patience and help. I ran this command: sudo R CMD javareconf. Then I ran install.packages("rJava"). Then I commented out the line containing dyn.load(). Lastly, I moved db2jcc4.jar to a subdirectory. Now, the application runs perfectly.